# Best way to create ftp user on dedicated server

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ftp

I have installed php, apache, mysql on a ubuntu machine. I had created new ftp user with name as ftpuser and home directory set to /var/www/ftpuser.

I was able to connect to server and landing on proper directory, but my webserver user that i.e www:data was not able to genearte files and folders through script. So I changed the group of my ftpuser to www:data group and has given write permission to group. Now the problem I have is my myftp user is not able to change any folder and file though everything is owned by ftp user only. Please let me know what I am doing here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood you correctly I believe the mistake here was changing the ftpuser to the www-data group.

The folder `/var/www/ftpuser` belongs to ftpuser and the ftpuser group.

So rather than changing the group of the ftpuser to www-data (revert this change you did), how about adding the www-data user to the ftpuser group and then make the directory `/var/www/ftpuser` directory writeable to the ftpuser group.

Please note, add the www-data to the ftpuser group, do not change the www-data user's group.